# How to use JDBC in servlet?

Tags: java, jdbc

I try to make servlet which take file from my DB(PostgreSQL) and send it to cliet. I says:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {
        Connection ce = ConnectionManager.createConnection();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Statement sta = null;
    sta = ce.createStatement();
    String fileName="";
    byte[] file=null;
    int bufferSize = 8192;
    String sql=("SELECT files,filename FROM filestock WHERE num =(SELECT filestock_id FROM parcels_temp WHERE num="+num+")");
    ResultSet rs=sta.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next()){
        file = rs.getBytes("files");
        fileName=rs.getString("filename");
    }
}
```

So i just create connection and eclipse says me that i gonna surround each line in `Try/catch`. Whats wrong? Its bad idea usind JDBC in servlet and i have to make any deals with data base in another class?
 In this case how to send file to servlet? I gonna send it as `File` or something else i want use [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/483892/JSF/java/commandButton-commandLink) for send file to cliet from servlet.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing everything in the servlet is not a good programming practice. Try to use a 3 tier architecture..

```
request---->Servlet--->Manager---->DAO--->Database
```

Create another DAO(DatabaseAccessObject). Its nothing but another class which does only database operations. All these code which you have written in this servlet will go to a function in that class.

Next step is to create a Bean in which you will store the results.

Now return the bean from The DAO to this servlet.

Now the question comes? What are you going to do with the file and fileName?

If you want to download the file, just push it into the output stream. Make sure that you set the contentType.

EDIT:
Sample file download

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(my_file);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int length;
while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
in.close();
out.flush();
```

Comment: Can you give an example with file download?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check

Comment: Thanks for example. But where i have to set ContextType?

Answer (score 1):

part of the issue at least is that youre not closing the connection that you opened. this will, over some time, result in a connection leak and your application will eventually crash.
the general pattern for using such resources is

```
Connection conn;
try {
   conn = ...
   //do stuff with your connection
   return result;
} catch (Exceptions ...) {
   ///handle exceptions
} finally {
   conn.close(); //will always be executed
}
```

also, as stated elsewhere, JSPs are considered "presentation layer" - meaning they mainly deal with nicely displaying data that originated elsewhere. that elsewhere is usually called the "business layer", and thats where database access usually belongs. so move that code over to a utility class, and call that class from your JSP

Comment: You mean that i just gonna push everything what binding with connection in same `try{...}`?

Comment: well, you could nest them (have an inner try{...} for dealing with the result sets if you want) but you need some way to make absolutely sure there's no execution path that doesnt close() your connection. try/finally is the easiest way.

Comment: Something going wrong becouse in `finally{conn.close()}` eclipse says that i gonna put try/catch there.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong. whenever you are accessing database there are many steps involved.

- registering the driver
- opening the connection
- executing query.
- getting the data
- closing the connection

These steps may throw exceptions which need to be handled.
I would suggest wrapping the whole code under one try/catch 
rather that writing it for each one of the statements.